# SQL The Default ELSE Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

in the following sql query i have a select case without else

```
 SET dateformat mdy 
    DECLARE @DATE1 DATETIME 
    SET @DATE1 = '12/31/2011' 
    DECLARE @DATE2 DATETIME 
    SET @DATE2 = '06/01/2012' 


    UPDATE tablx
    SET xdate = case WHEN xdate is null and odate BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2 then odate end
```

does the existance of else make difference, in the above case would the xdate value be filled with `NULL` if the condition is not met even if i didnt write `ELSE NULL`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't make any semantic difference `ELSE NULL` is the default if omitted.

Perhaps including the redundant `ELSE` explicitly might be clearer for potential readers unaware of this fact though.

Comment: i got aware of it after i messed up my table, thank god it was inside a select :D

Comment: @user1570048 - Are you saying you **don't** in fact want the `ELSE NULL` semantics? You could use `ELSE xdate` to use the column value as the default though in an `UPDATE` you are better off just excluding these rows in the `WHERE`

Answer (score 2):

From the MSDN documentation on [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

> ELSE else_result_expression
>
> Is the expression returned if no comparison operation evaluates to TRUE. If this argument is omitted and no comparison operation evaluates to TRUE, CASE returns NULL.

---

On a side note, it's a better habit to get into to write your date literals as:

```
DECLARE @DATE1 DATETIME 
SET @DATE1 = '20111231'
```

Because such literals (YYYYMMDD, no separators) aren't ambiguous - you can then ignore the `DATEFORMAT` settings that are in effect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they would.

For example, if you have the values

```
create table tablx (xdate datetime, odate datetime)

insert into tablx values ('2012-01-01', '2012-01-02')
insert into tablx values (null,         '2012-01-02')
insert into tablx values (null,         '2013-11-12')
insert into tablx values ('2013-11-11', '2013-11-12')
```

The first, third, and fourth rows would be updated to null, and the second would be updated to  '2012-01-02', so in effect

```
case WHEN <something> then odate end
```

is equivalent to

```
case WHEN <something> then odate else null end
```

But i would prefer the second version, as it is more explicit and obvious.